# Can I wipe HHD and install Ubuntu all from SD card?

Tags: installation, boot, eeepc, sd-card

I have an Asus Eee PC running on Windows XP. Recently, it crashed and when it boots, it has a black screen. This is a pain, as I only wanted to turn it on so I could wipe XP and install Ubuntu.

Is there any way I can load Ubuntu on an SD card and with a program (similar or in addition to the Linux Pen Drive installer) that will wipe the existing OS and install Ubuntu from the SD card? There is nothing important on the computer, so I want to completely wipe everything and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. deploy your Ubuntu image on SD card, plug in the USB holder and set USB boot in your bios. boot up and choose `Erase disk and install Ubuntu` as shown here:

[image]

You can see full instructions here:
[Ubuntu Graphical Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)